# I am getting snapshot as nil when I try to fetch data from Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch data from a Firestore database of my current user. But the snapshot is returning `nil`.

```swift
func fetchData() {
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "no uid"
    
    db.collection("patients").document(uid).getDocument { docSnap, error in
        if let error = error {
            debugPrint("there was an error\(error)")
        } else {
            print("there wasnt any errror")
            if  let data = docSnap?.data() as? [String: Any]   {
                print("data is \(data)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want the data of current user that I have stored in Firestore. I have stored the data in a collection named "patients" and inside there is a document with uid and inside there are fields like email, firstname, lastname, etc.

Comment: what if the `uid` is undefined? you don't have if condition to check `uid`

Comment: @YuvarajM i am getting the uid . I tried adding breakpoints and printing it . It works . if there is not uid it will print "no uid"

Comment: double check ur read write rules and error message. 
also check your collection name and document id is matched with the table or firebase

Comment: also note that its an async fetch so you have to wait a little to for printing data or error.

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadII yeah there was a mistake in the uid . Solved it !